# Minimum rookie child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the sportspress plugin and the rookie theme.

I want to remove the last name from the players which I can do by modifying a filter.
I was reading that it is bad to modify the original code and instead it's recommended to create a child theme.

This means, that I should create a child theme of rookie. But when I do this and just add the basics from the official wordpress documentation, the design of my page changes.

This is the code which I used:

style.css

```css
/*
 Theme Name:   Rookie (Sportspress) Child
 Description:  Rookie (Sportspress) Child Theme
 Author:       David
 Template:     rookie
 Text Domain:  rookiechild
*/
```

functions.php

```php
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

Why is it not displayed the same as the parent theme? What is the minimum code to make it look the same way?

Comment: are those two files in a seperate folder (the child theme folder) which is on the same level as the parent theme folder?

Comment: in the themes folder there is: rookie & rookie-child (& twentytwenty & oceanwp, but they are not active)
rookie-child has the two files style.css & functions.php on root level. There are no other files or folders.